# "@Override" in Java

Tags: java, android

I am learning Java to build an android app. I see that at a lot of places, where a class is getting inherited, the over ridden methods are marked by "`@Override`".

For eg:

```
@Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

Can some one explain, how does compiler interprets this token "`@Override`". Is it a reserved word or a comment. Or is just the "`@`" that does anything special like we have "`//`" for commenting out.

Comment: it tells the compiler that the method with @Override annotation is an overridden method.

Comment: Take a look at Java Anootations https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/

Answer (score 1):

The annotation `@Override` will cause an error if the method that is annotated is *not* from a supertype (a parent class or interface)

[JLS-9.6.3.4 @Override](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.3.4) says (in part),

> If a method declaration is annotated with the annotation @Override, but the method does not override or implement a method declared in a supertype, or is not override-equivalent to a public method of Object, a compile-time error occurs.

Comment: @TheLostMind Edited. How do you think it reads now?

Answer (score 1):

`@Override` is an annotation.

Use this so that you can take the advantage of the compiler checking to make sure you actually are overriding a method from parent class. In this way, even if you make mistakes such as misspelled a method name or not correctly matching the parameters, you will be warned by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

When `overriding a method`, you might want to use the `@Override` annotation that instructs the compiler that you intend to override a method in the `superclass`. If, for some reason, the compiler detects that the method does not exist in one of the `superclasses`, then it will generate an error.

refer [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

[From Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/predefined.html)
**@Override:** [@Override](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html) annotation informs the compiler that the element is meant to override an element declared in a superclass. Overriding methods will be discussed in Interfaces and Inheritance.

```
 // mark method as a superclass method
 // that has been overridden
 @Override 
 int overriddenMethod() { }
```

> While *it is not required to use this annotation when overriding a method*, **it helps to prevent errors.** If a method marked with `@Override` fails to correctly override a method in one of its superclasses, the compiler generates an error.

Answer (score 0):

The at sign character `(@)` indicates to the compiler that what follows is an **annotation**. In the following example, the annotation's name is **Override**:

```
@Override
void mySuperMethod() { ... }
```

[annotation refrance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/basics.html)

In your example `@Override` indicated that `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method does overrides or implements a method declared in a supertype, if `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` not present in super class it cause error.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {}
```